# Complex for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I what to do an incremental for loop in R. For instance, I  have a sample data below:

```
index=0
cnt<-c(6,7,8,5)
for(i in 1:length(cnt))
{
  for(j in 1:cnt[i])
  {
    index=index+1
  }
  
  print(index)
  
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
[1] 6
[1] 13
[1] 21
[1] 26
```

Now what I want to do is that I want to add another for loop that loops through value of `index`. For example:

```
 length=0
    cnt<-c(6,7,8,5)
    for(i in 1:length(cnt))
    {
      for(j in 1:cnt[i])
      {
        length=length+1
      }
      
      for(inner in 1:length)
      {
        print(inner)
      }
    }
```

But this is not giving me the desired output because it starts from 1 every time i run it.

The output I am expecting is:

```
for the first iteration:
1,2,3,4,5,6

second iteration:
7,8,9,10,11,12,13

third iteration:
14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21

fourth iteration:
22,23,24,25,26
```

Basically, length is the number of iteration for `inner` variable but it should start from the last value of `length`.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this with `Map`

```
cnt1 <- cumsum(cnt)
Map(`:`, c(1, cnt1[-length(cnt1)]+1), cnt1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#[[2]]
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13

#[[3]]
#[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21

#[[4]]
#[1] 22 23 24 25 26
```

---

Also, with `for` loop, can do

```
cnt <- c(6,7,8,5)
tmp_prev <- 1
tmp <- cnt[1]
for(i in seq_along(cnt)) {
    if(i == 1) {
       tmp_prev <- tmp_prev
       tmp <- cnt[i]
        
    } else {
       tmp_prev <- tmp_prev + cnt[i-1]    
       tmp <- tmp + cnt[i]
       }
       
    for(i in seq_along(tmp)) {
       print(tmp_prev[i]:tmp[i])
    }
}
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
#[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
#[1] 22 23 24 25 26
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create sequence from 1 to max to `cumsum` value of `inds`. Using `findInterval` we can create breaks to split the data.

```
inds <- cumsum(cnt)
inds1 <- seq(max(inds))
split(inds1, findInterval(inds1, inds, left.open = TRUE))

#$`0`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#$`1`
#[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13

#$`2`
#[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21

#$`3`
#[1] 22 23 24 25 26
```